# How can I resize the image widgets while maintaing the aspect ratio of all the widgets inside a row?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I wanted to design this UI using `Row`:
[image]

**I have a similar scenario where I don't know the size and orientation of the images.**
This is what I can think of: Put all the image widgets and wrap it within a row. But since I don't know the size as well as the orientation of the images, the widgets will not be properly placed as in the above image.

I've tried resizing the images by using scale factor. But since the size varies, the images are never uniformly scaled. Also whenever the orientation is different for a particular image, the UI ca not scale itself accordingly.

I would like to get an idea on how can this type of UI can be created in Flutter?

*Note: I don't own the copyrights of the image. Using this screenshot for only educational purpose from [here](https://www.pixpa.com/example/preview/?url=https://www.mromoart.com)*.

Comment: Have you tried using the AspectRatio widget along with the IntrinsicHeight/Width widgets?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) with `flex`:

```
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(child: Image("1")),
          flex: 2,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(child: Image("2"),
          flex: 2,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(child: Image("3"),
          flex: 1,
        ),
       ],
      ),
```

It is also worth looking into [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) .

Answer (score 2):

**Wrap** widget is what you need with of course little customization as well.

What is it do does is basically wrap all the widgets in a single row with spaces that you want with width dynamically. Give it shot!

- Here's the official [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html).
- Here's a [medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-wrap-widget-e1ee0b005b16) article explaining it well.